# Quickbooks DB Microsoft Query SQL string edit to render all data from a table

Tags: sql, odbc, quickbooks

I have a SQL string that is from a report in Quickbooks that I am running through MS Query over an ODBC connection.  I have successfully made a few minor edits to it.  This report is a Profit and Loss statement showing general ledger accounts with dollar values for each class (identifier for those dollar amounts, basically a company code) where the accounts are the rows and the classes are the columns.  I would like to pull ALL data for the class table, however I only have the SQL language screen.  So my question is either:

What do I add to this SQL language to force the query to show all classes (categories) from the table regardless of whether there is account data (dollars) within them?

OR Is there some way to show the tables so that I can edit them in this report where I only have the SQL string? Then what kind of function would I need to use to set this parameter.

This is the SQL text:

sp_report ProfitAndLossByClass show Amount_Title, Text, Label, Amount parameters DateMacro = 'LastMonth', SummarizeColumnsBy = 'Class'

Any thoughts on how to either open the tables from this report or how I can add to my SQL string to allow the report to show all classes names from the table would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Amy

Answer (score 0):

This query is calling a [Stored Procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) called sp_report and passing some parameters to it. I don't have QuickBooks, so there is no way I can tell you what sp_report does - maybe you can find out?

I'd check your Quickbook licence, though. Software suppliers often have clauses forbidding reverse engineering, which is what you're doing.